# Ajax call to controller, on success redirect to another page an display data return from Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call an `ActionMethod` inside the `controller` and if data has been successfully returned, I want to redirect the user to a new page and display the data within a `div` on the new page! Obviously when data is returned, the `div` still has not been loaded and therefore I cannot get the data displayed.

Any other way to do it?

```
test1: function () {        
    var type = $("#type1").val();        

    $.ajax({
        url: '/testcontroller/method1',
        type: "POST",
        data: { type: type }
    })
    .always(function () {

    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log("finished");
        xxx.xxxxxx.test2();
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        console.log("failed");
    })
},
test2: function() {
    var type = $("#type1").val();        

    var vm =
    {
        type: type
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/testcontroller/method2',
        type: "POST",
        data: { request:vm }
    })
    .always(function () {
        console.log("always");
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log("done");
        window.location.replace("/testpage");
        jQuery(window).load(function () {                
            $("#testdiv").replaceWith(data);
        });
    })
    .fail(function (data) {
        console.log("failed");
    })
},
```

Also both functions have a racing condition and sometimes they make conflict with each other, but even if I separate them, the first question remains.

Comment: When you go to a new page, the old page is gone, including all the js and data.  You'll have to "save" the ajax result somehow, either in a local storage or cookie, or send it back to the server and let the server send it back down to the browser.

Comment: Without worrying about data you should redirect to new location after method1 returns success. And when new page is rendering it should retrieve data from method2 either as part of model or may be by another ajax call from the new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Chetan and Chris were right. You loose all data being returned by `Ajax` on page reload. I got around this by storing request parameters in `Session` and called it again from the new page.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
// page 1
<form action="/testpage" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="old_data" id="old_data">
</form>

<script>

.done(function (data) {
    console.log("done");

    $('#old_data').val(data);
    $('#myForm').submit();
})

</script>

// testpage
if(isset($_POST['old_data'])) {
    echo '<div id="testdiv">'.$_POST['old_data'].'</div>';
}
```